# parse, query with compound sort?

Tags: parse-platform

I am using parse for one of my iOS apps. I want to write a cloudCode function that I can call from the client that queries for objects of class "A". So, I know how to do that. What I am trying to figure out is if I can sort the query by two fields at the same time.

"A" has an "**age** field and a "**count**" filed.

I want to be able to get all "**A**" objects sorted by "**age**" and **then** by "**count**"

How can I setup such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Code:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("A");
query.ascending("age,count");
```